# How to use focus and out of focus with Angular 4

Tags: angular, focus

I have a list of  created using ngFor in a component called recipe-list. All items are built using the component recipe-item. I want to change the style of a particular item when it is on focus.

Here is the html:

For the recipe-item->

```
<a
  class="list-group-item clearfix" 
  (click)="onSelected()"
  style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <img src="{{ recipe.imagePath }}" alt="{{ recipe.name }}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; width: 60px; Height: 60px;">
    </span>
</a>
```

for the recipe-list->

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <app-recipe-item
    *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipes"
    [recipe]="recipeEl"></app-recipe-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the color border of the one and only  on focus

Comment: focus means , when its clicked ? right ?

Comment: For me is a state. After clicked, an element stays on focus until you click somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something but if all you want is to change color border of the focused element, why not using CSS only? like `.element:focus` selector?

Comment: That was my first idea. I tried but somehow it does not work on this <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To can take focus of element , you need add attribute "tabindex".

```
<a tabindex="0" ...>
```

After, you can style it with pseudo-class ":focus". Use CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did that and put the outline none on the css class and now everything is working just fine.